# How to undo changes in a file after multiple commits in Git?

Tags: git, git-revert

I'm working on a branch where I have changed file A in several commits and now I want to revert all changes from it so that file A's state is same as initial state it had when I had first created the branch. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git checkout <sha1_of_commit> file/to/restore
```

It will revert file to state **after** `<sha1_of_commit>` commit.

If you want to revert it to state **before** this commit use

```
git checkout <sha1_of_commit>~1 file/to/restore
```

Comment: This reverted my file back to the state it had "after" <sha1_of_commit>, but didn't revert the changes applied in that commit itself. Is there any way to revert to state before the first commit, that is to the original state of the file?

Comment: Let's say that ```sha``` of that commit is ```abcde```, then use ```git checkout abcde~1 file/to/restore```. ```~1``` means that you checkout one commit before ```abcde``` commit. I'll update answer with this info.

Comment: You can get initial state back only if you had commited it to git. If you didn't commited initial state, than you can get back only state after first commit of that file.

Comment: The file was already there when I created the branch from master so ~1 should revert it back to its initial state.